# Java For-Loop for only items in arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm not sure if I'm wording this correctly.
I have an array policies[10], it can hold 10 floats.

I have a method that adds a float to the array when it's initialized.
I have another method that totals up all the floats in the array together.
The thing is that when I only have 3/10 of the array filled up, I get a null error. Can someone show me how I can fix this?

policies is a list of a class, Policy.

```
public float totalCoverage(){
    float total = 0;
    for (Policy x : policies){
        total += x.amount;
                }
    return total;
}
```

For my test, I have 3/10 arrays, if i change the array size from 10 to 3, it works.

Comment: consider using getter and setter methods instead of directly accessing members like `x.amount`

Answer (score 5):

Well presumably you've got some elements of your array which have null values. You can just do:

```
for (Policy x : policies) {
    if (x != null) {
        total += x.amount;
    }
}
```

A *better* change would be to use a dynamically-sized collection like `ArrayList`, so that you didn't have null values to consider in the first place.

Comment: yup! that's it! so simple, i can't believe I let that slip out. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
public float totalCoverage(){
    float total = 0;
    for (Policy x : policies){
        if (x != null)
        total += x.amount;
                }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> For my test, I have 3/10 arrays, if i change the array size from 10 to
>   3, it works.

If i can interpret correctly, you only have 3 elements initialized in your array, remaining 7 elements are not initializaed, initializing the array doesn't mean that array elements are initialized. thus they get their default value. i..e, null  thus when you call null.amount it throw **NPE**.

**Null check :**

```
for (Policy x : policies) {
    if (x != null) {
        total += x.amount;
    }
    else {
         System.out.println("x is null");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public float totalCoverage(){

    float total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
       if(array[i] != null)
          total = total + array[i]
                }
       return total;
}
```

Comment: Why would you suggest using an explicit indexed for loop instead of the enhanced for loop?

Comment: @JonSkeet one possibility can be non creation of iterator objects that are used in enhanced for loops. We work in performance critical environments and found in profiling that there were huge no of iterator objects created. So we explicitly used indexed loop.